# Circuit problem with Zener diode acting like an open circuit due to voltage being less than breakdown voltage

Tags: diodes, zener

> [image]
>
> Find the current through Zener diode?  - JEE mains 2019

In the solution, initially, the same circuit without the Zener diode was taken and it was found that equivalent resistance is given as 1250 Ohms and hence the current through the whole flowing through the battery would be .01A.

From this, the voltage drop along the parallel resistors of \$R_2\$ in the same circuit was found as 7.5V.  Then it was said that due to this the Zener diode would act as a open circuit as the voltage is less than the Zener break down voltage of 10V (i.e: zero current).

I don't understand how we can make a statement on the circuit with Zener diode from a circuit without Zener diode/follow the last lines of the argument. I hope someone can give a more detailed explanation of what was going on there.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the explanation give in the solution for arguing that current through zener diode should be zero @mkeith

Comment: Can you solve / have you solved simpler circuits with a zener diode? The way we solve them is to first analyse the circuit **without** that zener diode present. We then determine what the **voltage** would be there where the zener is connected. If that voltage is **lower** than the zener voltage, the zener will not conduct so we have solved the circuit. If the voltage is **higher** than the zener voltage then the zener will conduct (**it will not short!!!**) and the voltage across the zener will be its zener voltage.

Comment: *Then it was said that due to this the Zener diode would act as a **short circuit** as the voltage is less than the Zener break down voltage of 10V (i.e: zero current).* This statement is **VERY WRONG**, when the voltage across a zener diode is **smaller** than the zener voltage, the zener diode **DOES NOT SHORT**, instead, it will behave as an **OPEN CIRCUIT**.

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct, I have fixed the post now. The problems I had done of Zener diode, we would say that voltage in that branch is same as Zener voltage but I couldn't answer this question because it came in a twisted way (and I couldn't follow the arguements of the solution)

Comment: You can convert R1, R2, and the 12V source to the Thevenin equivalent if you know how to do that. Then you will see why no current flows in the Zener.

Comment: Oh, I have heard of it but I never got around to actually studying (it is out of the syllabus for this exam) but I'll check it out @mkeith Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Are both R2's 1500 Ohms? It is a bit odd to have two resistors with the same reference designator.

Comment: Yes you are correct , both the resistors are 1500 Ohms( at least as taken by the intended solution) @mkeith